# Android: save audio recording locally?

Tags: android, audio, save, local, recording

How is it possible to save a file to the android phone rather than the sdcard? I know that for sdcard the way you do it is by calling Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteDirectory(); or something like that anyway I have it working that way. But I want to be able to save to my phone instead, do I need a permission in my manifest to do that? I have tried replacing the getexternalst.... to getDataDirectory instead but that didnt seem to work.

As always, please and thank you :)

EDIT---------------

03-15 21:29:26.213: W/dalvikvm(21686): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8578)
03-15 21:29:26.213: E/AndroidRuntime(21686): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 21:29:26.213: E/AndroidRuntime(21686): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.alphaphonefinder/com.alphaphonefinder.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Context#getFilesDir`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29)

To get the full path as String (assuming `this` is the Activity):

```
String path = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: thanks for the help but this would alter a lot of my program, is there anyway of getting a string form directory? which will then be pointed at by a method if you get what i mean?

Comment: ugh that makes the app crash :( and yes it is the Activity

Comment: i think its a nullpointer exception from what logcat is saying

ill post it in an edit

Comment: Are you doing that inside the `onCreate` or outside? if outside - move it inside.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to call `Context#openFileOutput(String, int)` which takes a String for the file name and an int specifying the mode and returns a FileOutputStream. Then call write on the FileOutputStream passing it a byte array of your data. Make sure to close the FOS when you're done.

edit:
If you just want the internal files directory, try `Context#getFilesDir` which returns a File, and `getPath()` or `getAbsolutePath()` on the file will return the directory as a String.

Comment: thanks for the help mate, just a quick question before i try this, is it possible to use just a string method like the way i get the directory for the sdcard i have: final String RECORDING_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteDirectory(); is there anything like this? would just save me a lot of time recoding and stuff

Comment: yeah tried that there but that just causes the app to fail sadly